# Bypass `-C` flag when unzipping tar archive

Tags: unix, tar, archiving

I have a `.tar.gz` archive with the following structure:

```
opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json
opt/
opt/mag/
opt/mag/sw/
opt/mag/sw/apps/
opt/mag/sw/apps/service/
opt/mag/etc/
opt/mag/etc/service.environment
opt/mag/etc/service.toml
```

And this `.tar.gz` archive is extracted using this command:

```
tar -zxf ../service.tar.gz -C opt/mag/ --strip-components=2
```

Thee issue is this will extract the `opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` file inside `opt/mag` so it will become: `opt/mag/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` which is obviously wrong. Notice the removal of `opt/client/` by `--strip-components=2`.

**The issue is that I cannot change the unzip command**

I've tried to hack it around by inserting 2 dummy directories to bypass `--strip-components=2` something like this:

```
dummy1/dummy2/opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json
opt/
opt/mag/
opt/mag/sw/
opt/mag/sw/apps/
opt/mag/sw/apps/service/
opt/mag/etc/
opt/mag/etc/service.environment
opt/mag/etc/service.toml
```

This way `--strip-components=2` will remove `dummy1/dummy2` and the config file will be extracted to `/opt/mag/opt/client/py/utils/mappings/templates/config.json` which is still wrong, because that `-C opt/mag` will force the extraction inside `opt/mag`.

Given the fact that **I cannot change the unzip command** is there anyway to bypass the `-C` switch or some way to hack it around?

**Also, I cannot edit or move files on the container where this archive is extracted**

Comment: Yes, in unix, you can do (darn near) anything you want.  You can move your own tar command (scripted) higher in the path order so it gets called first.  Your script can parse the command line, strip out the parts you don't want, then call THE REAL tar with the remaining command.  The world is your oyster.